# insert a string variable to textblock from diffrent form

Tags: c#, xaml

I Want after login and open main form type username in textblock

xmal code of main form

```
                    <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 15 0 7" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black">
                    </TextBlock>
```

part of login form code for login:

```
con.Open();
            string login = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username='" + ltxtusername.Text + "'and password='" + ltxtpassword.Password + "'";
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(login, con);
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read() == true)
            {
                new SplashScreen().Show();
                this.Hide();
            }

            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("invalid username or password, please try Again", "Login failed", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                ltxtusername.Text = "";
                ltxtpassword.Password = "";
                ltxtusername.Focus();
            }
```

I want insert ltxtusername in the textblock

Comment: Bobby (Drop)Tables will teach you ... Also storeing passwords as they are in database ?

Comment: yes,is it wrong?